# java how to distinguish a file encoding ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, encoding, utf-8

I have an Android Aplication that reads a file with SQL script to insert data into a SQLite DB.
However I need to know the exatly encoding of this file, I have an EditText that reads information from SQLite, and if the encoding is not right, it'll be shown as invalid characters like "?" instead of characters like "ç, í, ã".

I have the following code:

```
FileInputStream fIn  = new FileInputStream(myFile);
BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn, "ISO-8859-1"));
String aDataRow;
while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
    if(!aDataRow.isEmpty()){
        String[] querys = aDataRow.split(";");
        Collections.addAll(querysParaExecutar, querys);
    }
}
myReader.close();
```

---

this works for "ISO-8859-1" encoding, and works for UTF-8 if I set to "UTF-8" as a charset. I need to programatically detect the charset encoding (UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1) and apply the correct one to my code.
Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: There is no foolproof way to determine character encoding from the encoded character data alone.  There are heuristic approaches that even a cursory web search should have turned up, but the usual mechanism is to rely on the encoding to be specified separately from the content.

Comment: Usually the encoding is specified by whomever inserted the data or separately from the content

Comment: that's true, however the problem is: my users are going to edit the file, if they edit with windows notepad and save it, it'll always get the encoding as "ISO-8859-1". The original file encoding is "UTF-8".

Comment: I suggest you look for an encoding guessing library. Validating UTF-8 is pretty straight-forward, but when it comes Notepad and friends, you will get whatever 8-bit encoding is suitable for the user's localisation – eg. Polish `ł` can't be represented in ISO-8859-1. And for distinguishing different ISO-8859-_X_ encodings, you need statistics of character distributions in different languages.

Comment: Isn't ISO-8859-1 a full subset of UTF-8?  I would recommend just assuming UTF-8 instead of trying to calculate if the file is ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8.  The issue arises if the uploaded file's encoding is either Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-X.  In the cases of Windows-1252, I have written converters that look for the microsoft control characters and then either translate them to a more ascii based character or the proper UTF-8 characters.  For ISO-8859-X issues, er, you're on your own.  Sorry.

Comment: @hooknc: *US-ASCII* is a subset of UTF-8.  ISO-8859-1 is a subset in terms of character repertoire, but *not* in terms of encoded bytes.

Comment: You can't edit a text file without knowing which encoding to read it with and how to save back with the same, and which character set the encoding is for so as to avoid characters that aren't supported. Can you provide a template in a format that: explains it or influences the editors to default to the right thing or helps detect that the user inappropriately switched the encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem with the lib universal chardet.
It's working fine as expected.

```
FileInputStream fIn  = new FileInputStream(myFile);
byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
UniversalDetector detector = new UniversalDetector(null);
int nread;
while ((nread = fIn.read(buf)) > 0 && !detector.isDone()) {
    detector.handleData(buf, 0, nread);
}
detector.dataEnd();
String encoding = detector.getDetectedCharset();
String chartsetName = null;
if (encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("WINDOWS-1252")){
    chartsetName = "ISO-8859-1";
}
if (encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("UTF-8")){
    chartsetName = "UTF-8";
}

BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn, chartsetName));
```